# Getting Vue to work with IE11 via Browserify and Babel 6

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, browserify

I'm having trouble getting a Vue site to work consistently in IE11.  I'm currently trying to use browserify to transpile with Babel to ES5, but seemingly it isn't working consistently (it sometimes works, but then after making a non-change to a JS file (such as adding a space to the end of a line) and then recompiling it will suddenly not work).

I'm seeing errors such as:

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' in _typed_array.js
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error in _collection.js
```

So I believe this means the JS isn't being transpiled correctly into ES5?

Here's a copy of my package.json that contains all my build scripts:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watch-js": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e rest-theme/src/main.js -o rest-theme/dist/build.js",
    "watch-scss": "./node_modules/.bin/node-sass -w --output-style=compressed scss/style.scss rest-theme/dist/build.css",
    "dev": "npm run watch-scss | npm run watch-js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify rest-theme/src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > rest-theme/dist/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "mixitup": "^3.2.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-moment": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.13",
    "viewport-units-buggyfill": "^0.6.0",
    "vivus": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "browserify-hmr": "^0.3.5",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.0.6",
    "vueify": "^9.3.0",
    "vueify-insert-css": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-migration-helper": "^1.1.1",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      ["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common"
  }
}
```

Nothing is really jumping out at me as to why it isn't compiling correctly; but perhaps there is something incorrect in my syntax, or an old version of something that is causing the build to fail sometimes?

I'm also including the babel polyfill on the first line of my main JS file:

```
import "babel-polyfill"; 
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
.....
```

But perhaps that is implemented incorrectly?

Let me know if I can provide more info, or additional script pieces to help illuminate anything!

Comment: side note: for your `watch-scss` script, you dont have to include the full path to the binary, npm looks for these first before going to the system level. What this means is that for that script you can shorten it to just: `node-sass -w --output-style=compressed ...` similar to what you already have for `cross-env` and `watchify`

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  updated node-sass as such

Comment: you dev script has pipes it in, which is odd since there isn't any input to pipe between commands, try changing it to `"dev": "npm run watch-scss & npm run watch-js",`. This will run these commands concurrently as opposed to using two && which will wait for the previous program (on the right-side before the &&'s) to end before running the next command.

Comment: Thanks again - I updated my dev script to use the ampersands instead of pipes.